# Blue water from copper pipes after flushing with chlorine

Tags: water

We have blue water and think something is corroding the copper pipes. Have recirculaters. Problem started after flushing with chlorine and now flushed with sodium bicarbonate. Ideas?

Comment: Is this in the hot side, the cold side, or both? Are you on city water or a well?

Answer (score 3):

A little knowledge is a dangerous thing.

You have created copper chloride dihydrate in your drinking water.  It's deadly in high concentrations and is not permitted in drinking water at levels above 5 ppm.  You should flush your pipes out with vinegar or another weak acid (just use vinegar, its safe and doesn't run the risk of creating new problems). It will dissolve the copper salt and remove it from your water. Then flush the system out with sodium bicarbonate to neutralize any residual acid salts that may have formed.

And for the love of god, have your water tested before anyone suffers liver or kidney failure from copper salt poisoning.